# "Sweep the strings of"

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language

Is **sweep the strings of something** idiomatic?

I came across this sentence in a [Slate article](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/politics/2017/05/how_to_manage_your_idiot_president.html)--I actually first read it in a [Merriam Webster example sentence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/numberless).

> Methods for **sweeping the strings of** Trump’s self-interest are as numberless as the stars in the sky.

I can't seem to find this idiom defined in online dictionaries. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a common idiom. It may be a metaphor that was invented by the author of the article.

The metaphor relates to playing a guitar or other stringed instrument by *strumming* it (instead of picking individual notes) Its an easy way to get a sound from a guitar.

The metaphor implies that it is as easy to manipulate Trump as it is to strum a guitar.